# How to apply knapsack method in this algorithmic puzzle?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Suppose you have got a list of items along with their `Weights[]` and `Price[]`.
Now given two integers `N<=100` and `K<=100` you have to find the minimum amount of money you should spend such that total weight of the items you have bought is exactly equal to K and number of items do not exceed N and if it is not possible to satisfy given conditions just print a `IMPOSSIBLE`.
You can buy each item as many times you want.

Please tell me how to apply knapsack in this problem and if it is not a knapsack problem then how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dp[i] = minimum money you have to pay to get weight i

dp[_] = infinity

for i = 1 to N do
  for j = item[i].weight to MaxWeight do
    dp[j] = min(dp[j], dp[j - item[i].weight] + item[i].price)
```

If `dp[K] != infinity`, that is your solution, otherwise there is no solution. The practical efficiency depends on how you compute `MaxWeight`: either sum all of the item weights, or try to be smarter about it.

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting a Dynamic Programming (DP) solution, and not exactly a Knapsack problem. Though, Knapsack has a DP solution.

The solution for your case is to form necessary recurrence. Since you are targeting to minimize on money, each state transition will be to add to weight and item number to form a new state.

So, your state space is: `DP[Weight][Item]`

The coding is left as an exercise.